# The formatter 'Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter' is using the deprecated formatter API

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am using cucumber version 3.1.0. While executing `cucumber-ruby` test, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: The formatter Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter is using the deprecated formatter API which will be removed in v4.0 of Cucumber.
```

I have no clue where to change this. Where can I change the `Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter`, and which formatter would you recommend to use instead?

Comment: Based on the warning message I would check if it could be configured on the [TeamCity server](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

Comment: I think you should just log a bug with Teamcity. They've had compatibility [problems with their formatter and Cucumber before](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17157).

Comment: Cucumber maintainer here. I totally agree with @JustinKo. If that doesn't get you anywhere I'd ask the Cucumber mailing list to see if anybody else has dealt with this problem. It wouldn't solve the issue since that's with TeamCity but somebody might know a way to work around it.

Comment: This looks like something TeamCity needs to fix (and you might need to wait for their fix before upgrading your Cucumber version).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by several people in comments, this means that Teamcity needs to update the version of the Cucumber Formatter they are using. 
Once they have, you might need to update your version of Teamcity.